# How to use a Boolean variable in an if statement to change text (C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boolean

So i am trying to create a simple text adventure in unity and i have written a script the changes the state of the text depending on key presses. To try and add a bit of complexity i have attempted to add a system where when in one state it is displayed that an item is picked up and the variable for that item has been set to true which is stated at the top of the script. Then, when the user next enters a different state it is checked to see if the variable is true or false in which if the variable is true different text will be displayed to if it where false. My issue is that every time i enter the state withe the IF statements the variable is automatically set to false no matter what. An answer would be more than appreciated :).

**Engine:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class TextController : MonoBehaviour {

public Text text;
private enum states {cell, floor, CellDoor, mirror, bed, rock, shard};
private states myState;
bool rock;
bool shard;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        rock = false;
        shard = false;
        myState = states.cell; 
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {    
        print (myState);
        if (myState == states.cell){
            state_cell ();
        }else if (myState == states.floor){
            state_floor ();
        }else if (myState == states.CellDoor){
            state_CellDoor ();
        }else if (myState == states.mirror){
           state_mirror ();
        }else if (myState == states.bed){
            state_bed ();
        }else if (myState == states.rock){
            state_rock ();
        }else if (myState == states.shard){
            state_shard ();
        }
    }
```

**Variable change:**

```
void state_rock (){
        rock = true;
        text.text = "You conjure what strength you have and eagerly pry at a slightly loose looking part of the concrete " +
                    "with your blistered hands. Finally a piece breaks free, you drop it into one of your pockets.\n\n" +
                    "You have obtained a rock! \n\n" +
                    "Press R to return to the cell.";               
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R)){
        myState = states.cell;
    }
    print(rock);
```

**Statements that don't work:**

```
void state_mirror (){
    print (rock);
    if (rock = true);{
        text.text = "A rather old fashioned mirror, strangely clean and drilled into the wall. Shattering the mirror and " +
                    "wielding a shard could prove useful. You remember the hefty chunk of concrete in your pocket. \n\n" +  
                    "Press T if you would like to throw the rock at the mirror or R if you would like to return to the cell";
    }
    if (rock = false);{
        text.text = "A rather old fashioned mirror, strangely clean and drilled into the wall. Shattering the mirror and " +
                    "wielding a shard could prove useful. You are unable to think of any way of shattering the mirror " +
                    "as it is rigidly screwed into the wall, perhaps a blunt object would do the trick?. \n\n" +
                    "Press R to return to the cell.";
    }                           
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R)){
        myState = states.cell;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.T)){
        myState = states.shard;
    }

}
```

[Console saying item is obtained, 'true'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnB87.jpg)

[Console saying that the item has not been obtained for some reason, 'false'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSWlW.jpg)

Comment: there is a difference between `=` and `==` I would suggest you do some more reading on Basic C# concepts

Comment: `if (rock = true);{` In that line, the semicolon terminates the if statement. Ends it. It means the `if` controls an *empty statement* -- meaning the if either executes an empty statement (doing nothing), or doesn't execute the empty statement (also doing nothing). The block in curly braces after it has nothing to do with the `if`. It just executes. In addition to fixing the mistaken use of `=`, you need to get rid of the semicolon.

Comment: Since `states` is an enum, that's all the more reason to change your `Update` method to use a `switch` instead of a series of `if/else` calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there are several problems in your script.

Lets start with this :

```
 if (rock = true);{...
```

You need to realize that you are assign rock = true, you need to use double equals to compare. Even more, is advisable to use if(boolVar) , because automatically will execute if it's true.

```
if(rock){ do something }
//is the same that 
if(rock == true){}
```

Also, another important thing, is that you should not put a ; after the if, because when you do that the code inside the brackets will not be related to the conditional.

Comment: I realise how much of a rookie error this was, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are some obvious problems with these statements.

```
if (rock = true);{
        text.text = "A rather old fashioned mirror, strangely clean and drilled into the wall. Shattering the mirror and " +
                    "wielding a shard could prove useful. You remember the hefty chunk of concrete in your pocket. \n\n" +  
                    "Press T if you would like to throw the rock at the mirror or R if you would like to return to the cell";
    }
    if (rock = false);{
        text.text = "A rather old fashioned mirror, strangely clean and drilled into the wall. Shattering the mirror and " +
                    "wielding a shard could prove useful. You are unable to think of any way of shattering the mirror " +
                    "as it is rigidly screwed into the wall, perhaps a blunt object would do the trick?. \n\n" +
                    "Press R to return to the cell.";
    }
```

You don't put a semicolon at the end of an `if`, and the `=` sign by itself, asigns the value on the right to the variable on the left before it is evaluated. So change the single `=` to a `==`.

Your code becomes,

```
if (rock == true){
        text.text = "A rather old fashioned mirror, strangely clean and drilled into the wall. Shattering the mirror and " +
                    "wielding a shard could prove useful. You remember the hefty chunk of concrete in your pocket. \n\n" +  
                    "Press T if you would like to throw the rock at the mirror or R if you would like to return to the cell";
    }
    if (rock == false){
        text.text = "A rather old fashioned mirror, strangely clean and drilled into the wall. Shattering the mirror and " +
                    "wielding a shard could prove useful. You are unable to think of any way of shattering the mirror " +
                    "as it is rigidly screwed into the wall, perhaps a blunt object would do the trick?. \n\n" +
                    "Press R to return to the cell.";
    }
```

Though a better way to write this would be,

```
if (rock) // is the same as if rock == true
{
        text.text = "A rather old fashioned mirror, strangely clean and drilled into the wall. Shattering the mirror and " +
                    "wielding a shard could prove useful. You remember the hefty chunk of concrete in your pocket. \n\n" +  
                    "Press T if you would like to throw the rock at the mirror or R if you would like to return to the cell";    
}
else // is the same as if rock == false (in this case)
{
        text.text = "A rather old fashioned mirror, strangely clean and drilled into the wall. Shattering the mirror and " +
                    "wielding a shard could prove useful. You are unable to think of any way of shattering the mirror " +
                    "as it is rigidly screwed into the wall, perhaps a blunt object would do the trick?. \n\n" +
                    "Press R to return to the cell.";    
}
```